# Breaking text line when reaching the image in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, text, flutter-layout, line-breaks, longtext

I have the long multiple line text with the Image at the top right corner
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQvLh.png)
So, how to detect if the text reaches the image and then break the line ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use with this library as [drop_cap_text](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/drop_cap_text)